# Translate Transformation Matrices for Alpha Blending

Tags: matlab, matrix, translation, transformation, panoramas

I'm trying to introduce alpha blending into the [MATLAB panoramic stitching example](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/feature-based-panoramic-image-stitching.html). The algorithm successfully blends, but the stitched image is translated, when using the example's "tforms" transformation matrices.

The alpha blending code is here:

```
%% merge images using Alpha blending
%  input:   imgs - source images
%           mask - image mask
%           transforms - transformation matrices to transform each images
%                        into the new coordinate system
%           newHeight, newWidth - size of the new coordinate system
%  output:  newImg - merged image
function [ newImg ] = alphaBlend( imgs, mask, transforms, newHeight, newWidth )
% image information
height = size(imgs, 1);
width = size(imgs, 2);
nChannels = size(imgs, 3);
nImgs = size(imgs, 4);
% alpha mask
mask = imcomplement(mask);
mask(1, :) = 1;
mask(end, :) = 1;
mask(:, 1) = 1;
mask(:, end) = 1;
mask = bwdist(mask, 'euclidean');
mask = mask ./ max(max(mask));
% backward transformation
backTransforms = zeros(size(transforms));
for i = 1 : nImgs
    backTransforms(:, :, i) = inv(transforms(:, :, i));
end
% image merging
newImg = zeros([newHeight newWidth nChannels], 'uint8');
for y = 1 : newHeight
    for x = 1 : newWidth
%         p1 = [y; x; 1];
        p1 = [x; y; 1];
        pixelSum = zeros(nChannels, 1);
        alphaSum = 0;
        for k = 1 : nImgs
%             p2 = backTransforms(:, :, k) * p1;
            p2 = p1' * backTransforms(:,:,k);
            p2 = p2 ./ p2(3);
            xx = p2(1);
            yy = p2(2);
            p2 = [yy; xx; 1];
            if p2(1) >= 1 && p2(1) < height && p2(2) >= 1 && p2(2) < width
                i = floor(p2(2));
                a = p2(2) - i;
                j = floor(p2(1));
                b = p2(1) - j;
                pixel = (1 - a) * (1 - b) * imgs(j, i, :, k)...
                    + a * (1 - b) * imgs(j, i + 1, :, k)...
                    + a * b * imgs(j + 1, i + 1, :, k)...
                    + (1 - a) * b * imgs(j + 1, i, :, k);
                alpha = (1 - a) * (1 - b) * mask(j, i)...
                    + a * (1 - b) * mask(j, i + 1)...
                    + a * b * mask(j + 1, i + 1)...
                    + (1 - a) * b * mask(j + 1, i);
                pixelSum = pixelSum + double(squeeze(pixel)) * double(alpha);
                alphaSum = alphaSum + double(alpha);
            end
        end
        newImg(y, x, :) = pixelSum / alphaSum;
    end
end
end
```

After the Panoramic Stitching example tforms matrices have been formed by [step 4](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/feature-based-panoramic-image-stitching.html#d119e4584) , I try translating the image this way:

```
mask = ones(imageSize(1),imageSize(2));
% Create the panorama.
% Alpha blending
horiz = 200;
verti = 100;
Translate = [1, 0, 0; 0, 1, 0; horiz, verti, 1];
transforms = Translate * tforms(1).T;
for i =1:numel(tforms) transforms(:,:,i) = Translate * tforms(i).T; end
 panorama1 = alphaBlend( temp, mask, transforms, height, width );
```

But, the resulting image overlap is off. How do I translate the tforms matrix, in order to translate the stitched panoramic image?